# HTTPS of for a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

My site has a normal SSL installed and these are the changes I made in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=blog.mysite.com
```

But I want https://blog.mysite.com to redirect to http://blog.mysite.com

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete problem. Actually when I open blog.mysite.com it shows a SSL error.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog.assurehosts.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.assurehosts.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Just note I'm writing it off top of my head; I don't have any server nearby to test it.

*edit*: added `R=301` to make this a permanent redirect since that's what you probably want; and `L` to make sure following rules won't be applied if one matched already — I just recalled it.

Comment: I've just reordered yours and added the opposite. You could do that yourself ;P.

Comment: Haha thanks anyways. I can ask my senior to provide you a Hosting account for free! Just drop me your email and domain at aman@assurehosts.com if you need it. :)

Comment: I've also added 'permanent redirect' flag to the snippet, you'd probably want that to make browser remember the redirect and perform it without asking the server in the future.